# can't position label with round button to top corner kivy

Tags: python, position, label, kivy

I am trying to get a label with in it a rounded button to be placed in top left corner, but can't seem to get it done.

tried pos_hint in both < BackLabel > and < SubScreen >-->backlabel.

excerpts from my code:

tryout.py:

```
class RoundedButton(Button):
    pass

class BackLabel(Label):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(BackLabel, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.RoundedButton=RoundedButton()
        self.add_widget(self.RoundedButton)  

class SubScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SubScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.BackLabel = BackLabel(id='bl')
        self.add_widget(self.BackLabel)
        self.OpenLink = Button(id= 'forward')   
        self.add_widget(self.OpenLink)
        self.Footer = Label(id='footer')
        self.add_widget(self.Footer)
```

.kv file:

```
<BackLabel@Label>:
    background_color: 0,0,0,0
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgb: 0, 1, 0
        RoundedRectangle:
            size: [100,100]
            radius: [50,]


<RoundedButton@Button>:
    background_color: 0,0,0,0  # the last zero is the critical on, make invisible
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (.4,.4,.4,1) if self.state=='normal' else (0,.7,.7,1)  # visual feedback of press
        RoundedRectangle:
            size: [100,100]
            radius: [50,]
    text:'<--Back'
    on_release: app.root.current = 'mainmenu'


<SubScreen>
    name: 'submenu'
    BackLabel:
        id: 'bl'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is difficult to interpret exactly what you are attempting to do. For example, why are you adding a `RoundedButton` to a `BackLabel` in the `__init__()` method of your `BackLabel`? Anyway, here is a simpler version of your code that does what I think you want. A couple things to note: In order to position a `Widget` meaningfully, it must have a reasonable `size`. The default `size` of any `Widget` is the same as its parent, so positioning it doesn't really make sense. So my code below sets the size of your `RoundButton` (which requires `size_hint` to be `(None, None)`. Finally, the position can be set (as in the `SubScreen` rule in the `kv` below):

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager


class SubScreen(Screen):
    pass


Builder.load_string('''
<RoundedButton@Button>:
    size_hint: (None, None)
    size: (100, 100)
    background_color: 0,0,0,0  # the last zero is the critical on, make invisible
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (.4,.4,.4,1) if self.state=='normal' else (0,.7,.7,1)  # visual feedback of press
        RoundedRectangle:
            pos: (self.center_x - 50, self.center_y - 50)
            size: self.size
            radius: [50,]
    text:'<--Back'
    on_release: app.root.current = 'mainmenu'


<SubScreen>
    name: 'submenu'
    RoundedButton:
        pos: (0, root.height-self.height)
''')


class TheApp(App):
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(SubScreen())
        return sm

TheApp().run()
```

Comment: thanks John Anderson. It worked. I know putting the button in a label was a bit weird, but the only way i got the button visible. Your edit to my pieces of code worked perfectly. Much appreciated.